# Are EdDSA algorithms encoded by ASN.1 DER standards?

Tags: encryption, keys, dsa, ed25519, asn.1

Is it required, or widely practiced to encode a EdDSA signature as a ASN.1 Sequence? Why or why not? How should you encode a EdDSA signature? I cannot find mention of DER or ASN in the [EdDSA RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032).

However, there is mention in the [ECDSA RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979) (as expected)

> An ECDSA signature is a pair of integers.  In many protocols that
> require a signature to be a sequence of bits (or octets), it is
> customary to encode the signature as an ASN.1 SEQUENCE of two INTEGER
> values, with DER rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An EdDSA signature is a sequence of bytes encoded according to the [EdDSA paper](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#ed25519) or its [extension to more curves](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#eddsa), or according to [RFC 8032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032), which should be treated as opaque by callers.

In particular, for an instance of EdDSA on a curve $E$ over a field $\mathbb F_p$ of order $p < 2^{b-1}$:

- A **public key** is a $b$-bit bit string $n \mathbin\| \underline y$ encoding a point $(x, y) \in E$, where $n$ is 1 if $x$ is ‘negative’ and 0 if not, and $\underline y$ is the little-endian encoding of the least nonnegative integer residue of $y \in \mathbb F_p$.  Here ‘negative’ means $\underline x$ is lexicographically larger than $\underline{-x}$.
- A **signature** is a $2b$-bit string $\underline R \mathbin\| \underline s$ encoding a point $R \in E$ like a public key, and a $b$-bit integer $s$ in little-endian encoding $\underline s$.

There is no ASN.1 formatting involved here.  Forget ASN.1, and forget ECDSA.  They are evil things.

Comment: [RFC 8410](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8410) changed the game.